# Find available USB devices Mac OS X

Tags: objective-c, macos, usb

I was wondering if there was any way to see if a usb device (only specific ones) are plugged in and unplugged using objective c.  All I need to know is if a device has been plugged in, such as an iPhone/iPod Touch.  If not, any other device will work

Thanks

Comment: Nice question. One vote up from me.

Answer (score 8):

The information in Apple's [USB Device Interface Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeviceDrivers/Conceptual/USBBook/USBIntro/USBIntro.html) (see the "USB Devices on Mac OS X" and "Finding USB Devices and Interfaces" sections) and [Accessing Hardware From Applications](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeviceDrivers/Conceptual/AccessingHardware/AH_Intro/AH_Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000376) (see the "Finding and Accessing Devices" section) docs should put you on the right track.

That said, I suspect you'll need to delve below the shiny Cocoa surface into the world of I/O Kit functions and (potentially) POSIX.